# How to remove duplicates from overlapped number ranges in python?

Tags: python

I have nested dictionaries that contain number ranges as below

I need to expand each range to numbers so I can list each number individually with the right tags (country, region, PBX if listed) without having duplicates. In case of duplicates, the smallest range remains.

for example, those overlapping ranges

```
976431[000-799]
9764317[00-99]
97643179[0-9]
```

would become

```
976431[000-699]
9764317[00-89]
97643179[0-9]
```

expected result:

```
list1_000, 976431000, Country=cz;Region=eu  
list1_001, 976431001, Country=cz;Region=eu  
list1_002, 976431002, Country=cz;Region=eu  
so on .....  
list1_699, 976431699, Country=cz;Region=eu  
list2_00, 976431700, Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=freepbx  
list2_01, 976431701, Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=freepbx  
list2_02, 976431702, Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=freepbx  
so on .....  
list2_89, 976431789, Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=freepbx  
list3_0, 976431790, Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=asterisk  
list3_1, 976431791, Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=asterisk  
list3_2, 976431792, Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=asterisk  
so on .....  
list3_9, 976431799, Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=asterisk
```

but I get triplicates (eg. 976431799):

```
list1_000, 976431000, Country=cz;Region=eu  
list1_001, 976431001, Country=cz;Region=eu  
list1_002, 976431002, Country=cz;Region=eu  
so on .....  
list1_799, 976431799, Country=cz;Region=eu  
list2_00, 976431700, Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=freepbx  
list2_01, 976431701, Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=freepbx  
list2_02, 976431702, Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=freepbx  
so on .....  
list2_99, 976431799, Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=freepbx  
list3_0, 976431790, Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=asterisk  
list3_1, 976431791, Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=asterisk  
list3_2, 976431792, Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=asterisk  
so on .....  
list3_9, 976431799, Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=asterisk
```

the script I'm using is

```
import numpy as np

MYRANGES = [
    {'Name': 'list1', 'Prefix': '976431[000-799]', 'Tag': 'Country=cz;Region=eu;'},
    {'Name': 'list2', 'Prefix': '9764317[00-99]', 'Tag': 'Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=freepbx;'},
    {'Name': 'list3', 'Prefix': '97643179[0-9]', 'Tag': 'Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=asterisk;'},
]

def ddi2csv(myranges):

    for myrange in myranges:
        prefixrange = myrange['Prefix'].replace(']', '').split('[')[0]
        suffixrange = myrange['Prefix'].replace(']', '').split('[')[1].split('-')

        for digit in np.arange(int(suffixrange[0]),
                               int(suffixrange[1]) + 1):
            suffix = f"{digit:{str(0) + str(len(suffixrange[0]))}}"
            print(
                str(myrange['Name'].lower()) + "_" + str(suffix),
                prefixrange + suffix,
                myrange['Tag']
                      )

ddi2csv(MYRANGES)
```

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done?

Comment: Beside the point, but a bunch of those `str()` calls are redundant. And why aren't you using f-strings everywhere? They're so much more readable than concatenation.

Comment: Also beside the point, but why bother with `np.arange` when you could just use `range`?

Comment: It'd help to minimize the data to make it easier to work with. (See [mre].) You could do, say `Prefix` values `'976431[796-799]'`, `'9764317[97-99]'`, and `'97643179[8-9]'`.

Comment: The duplicates have different PBX, so what would be the criteria to discard duplicates? Or should they be renamed (and which which criteria)?

Comment: In your expected result, you seem to be using shorter ranges: for `'list1'` you use `[000-699]` instead of `[000-799]`. Is that what you want? To cut the range short when it overlaps with the next one?

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this?

```py
ranges = [
    {"Name": "list1", "Prefix": "976431[000-799]", "Tag": "Country=cz;Region=eu;"},
    {
        "Name": "list2",
        "Prefix": "9764317[00-99]",
        "Tag": "Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=freepbx;",
    },
    {
        "Name": "list3",
        "Prefix": "97643179[0-9]",
        "Tag": "Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=asterisk;",
    },
]


def create_expanded_ranges(ranges):
    """
    Function takes in a list of ranges and returns a list of expanded ranges.

        Parameters:
            ranges (list): List of ranges to be expanded.

        Returns:
            expanded_ranges (list): List of expanded ranges.
    """
    expanded_ranges = []

    for range in ranges:
        expanded_ranges.append(expand_range(range))

    return expanded_ranges


def expand_range(user_range):
    """
    Function takes in a range and returns a list of expanded ranges.

        Example:
            expand_range({"Name": "list1", "Prefix": "976431[000-799]", "Tag": "Country=cz;Region=eu;"})
            returns:
                [
                    list1_000, 976431000, Country=cz;Region=eu,
                    list1_001, 976431001, Country=cz;Region=eu,
                    list1_002, 976431002, Country=cz;Region=eu,
                    ...
                ]

        Parameters:
            range (dict): Range to be expanded.

        Returns:
            expanded_ranges (list): List of expanded ranges.
    """

    expanded_ranges = []
    prefix = user_range["Prefix"]
    name = user_range["Name"]
    tag = user_range["Tag"]

    range_max = int(prefix.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split("-")[1]) + 1

    root_prefix = prefix.split("[")[0]

    for i in range(0, range_max):
        range_number = str(i).zfill(3)
        range_id = f"{root_prefix}{range_number}"
        range_name = f"{name}_{range_number}"

        expanded_ranges.append(
            [
                range_name,
                range_id,
                tag,
            ]
        )

    return expanded_ranges


if __name__ == "__main__":
    expanded_ranges = create_expanded_ranges(ranges)
   
    # Example Output:
    print(expanded_ranges[0][0])
    print(expanded_ranges[0][-1])

    print(expanded_ranges[1][0])
    print(expanded_ranges[1][-1])

    print(expanded_ranges[2][0])
    print(expanded_ranges[2][-1])
```

Example Output:

```bash
['list1_000', '976431000', 'Country=cz;Region=eu;']
['list1_799', '976431799', 'Country=cz;Region=eu;']
['list2_000', '9764317000', 'Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=freepbx;']
['list2_099', '9764317099', 'Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=freepbx;']
['list3_000', '97643179000', 'Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=asterisk;']
['list3_009', '97643179009', 'Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=asterisk;']
```

Answer (score 0):

that will find the most granular range (list 3) then expand it with individual numbers then remove the list 3 from MYRANGES list and start again until MYRANGES list is empty

```
import numpy as np  # To create list of numbers. For example, 00-99 will be 01, 02, 03, 04,...99

MYRANGES = [
    {'Name': 'list1', 'Prefix': '976431[000-799]', 'Tag': 'Country=cz;Region=eu;'},
    {'Name': 'list2', 'Prefix': '9764317[00-99]', 'Tag': 'Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=freepbx;'},
    {'Name': 'list3', 'Prefix': '97643179[0-9]', 'Tag': 'Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=asterisk;'},
]


def ddi2csv(myranges):
    prefixes = []
    duplicate = []
    while any(myranges):
        # Finding overlapping ranges and add the most granular ranges to prefixes list
        for myrange in myranges:
            if myrange.get('Prefix') is not None:
                prefixrange = myrange.get('Prefix').replace(']', '').split('[')[0]
                prefixes.append(prefixrange)
                for prefix in prefixes:
                    if int(prefixrange) > int(prefix):
                        prefixes.remove(prefix)
        # Expanding the most granular ranges to unique numbers and add them to duplicate list
        # then remove the range from myranges list
        for prefix in prefixes:
            for myrange in myranges:
                if myrange.get('Prefix') is not None and prefix in myrange.get('Prefix'):
                    prefixrange = myrange.get('Prefix').replace(']', '').split('[')[0]
                    suffixrange = myrange.get('Prefix').replace(']', '').split('[')[1].split('-')
                    for digit in np.arange(int(suffixrange[0]),
                                           int(suffixrange[1]) + 1):
                        suffix = f"{digit:{str(0) + str(len(suffixrange[0]))}}"
                        prefix = prefixrange + suffix
                        if prefix not in duplicate:
                            duplicate.append(prefix)
                            print(
                                str(myrange['Name'].lower()) + "_" + str(suffix),
                                prefix,
                                myrange['Tag']
                                      )
                    myrange.clear()


ddi2csv(MYRANGES)
```

result example

```
list3_0 976431790 Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=asterisk;
list3_1 976431791 Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=asterisk;
list3_9 976431799 Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=asterisk;
list2_00 976431700 Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=freepbx;
list2_01 976431701 Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=freepbx;
list2_89 976431789 Country=cz;Region=eu;Pbx=freepbx;
list1_000 976431000 Country=cz;Region=eu;
list1_001 976431001 Country=cz;Region=eu;
list1_699 976431699 Country=cz;Region=eu;
```